# Accept default in ivy filename prompt

Tags: minibuffer, ivy, doom, path, prompt

Using Doom Emacs, when I invoke a command (such as `diff`) that needs a filepath I get an `ivy` prompt that names a default value:

[image: ivy with default]

But I am unable to clear the line or somehow tell ivy to take that default. Does ivy even know about it? Can I force ivy to output an empty string?

I browsed the [ivy docs](https://oremacs.com/swiper) but to no avail

Comment: You can exit completion with an empty or the current input using `C-M-j` (`ivy-immediate-done`), documented under [`(info "(ivy) Key bindings for single selection action then exit minibuffer")`](https://oremacs.com/swiper/#key-bindings-for-single-selection-action-then-exit-minibuffer).

Comment: I know and use that binding, but it uses the current input - and I can't clear the input line, at least to my knowledge

Comment: With empty input, `C-M-j` should exit with the default offered by `diff`. Ivy doesn't support completely clearing the prompt during file name completion.

Comment: Thanks @Basil, you are right, I didn't try correctly yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ivy-immediate-done`](https://oremacs.com/swiper/#key-bindings-for-single-selection-action-then-exit-minibuffer) (defaults to <kbd>C-M-j</kbd>) without entering any text to use the default value.